# Rails GET method is called instead of DELETE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to delete a record using :method => :delete but its calling GET instead. It redirects to show and displays 404 not found. But if i go back and refresh, the record is acctualy deleted.

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
<div class='photogallery'>
<%= link_to image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb)) if photo.image? %>
<div class="name"><%= photo.caption %></div>
<div class="actions">
<%= link_to "edit", edit_admins_photogallery_path(photo) %> |
<%= link_to "remove",admins_photogallery_path(photo), :method => 'delete',:confirm => 'Are you sure?' %> |

</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-select
//= require jquery.timepicker
//= require jquery.ui.tabs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require jquery.ui.accordion
//= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
//= require strftime-min.js
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

i have included in my layout file and its been loaded fine.

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

The weird part is it used to work fine few days back,now it has stopped working for all the controllers.

edit: routes.rb

```
devise_for :users
root 'index#index'
resources :reprint
devise_scope :user do
get "/admins/", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
end
namespace :admins do
resources :location,:dashboard,:lodge,:room,:booking,:rate_calendar,:photogallery    
end  
resources :index do 
collection do
match 'search' => 'index#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
match 'location' => 'index#location', via: [:get, :post], as: :location
match  'add_cart' => 'index#add_cart', via: [:get, :post], as: :add_cart
end
end
resources :room_availability
```

edit: photogallery_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  @photos = Photogallery.find(params[:id])
 if @photos.destroy
  redirect_to admins_photogallery_path, notice: "Photo was successfully destroyed."
 else
  render :action => 'index'
  flash[:error] = "Photo could not be deleted."
 end
end
```

Comment: can i get your rout file

Comment: i have included route file

Comment: Do you have JS enabled?

Comment: yes others functionalities which uses JS works fine.

Comment: Are all DELETE requests broken or only ones that use this path/resource?

Comment: All the DELETE requests are broken.But the destroy action is being called because record gets deleted, but it redirects to show page and displays 404.

Comment: Can you post the destroy method in your controller? Are you sure it's not working correctly but then redirecting to the show page (which doesn't exist because the record's been deleted?)

Comment: i have included destroy method. it 1st goes to show page,then when i go back to index page and refresh the page,the record is deleted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def destroy
  @photos = Photogallery.find(params[:id])
 if @photos.destroy
  redirect_to admins_photogalleries_path, notice: "Photo was successfully destroyed."
 else
  render :action => 'index'
  flash[:error] = "Photo could not be deleted."
 end
end
```

I believe you have it set up correctly, you just made a typo in the redirect_to call. admins_photogallery_path is the show page. admins_photogalleries_path is the index page. There's no way you're making a GET request and reaching the destroy method unless you specified that specifically in the routes. The GET and DELETE verbs both talk to the same path - if you were indeed using a GET request, you'd simply go to the show page and nothing would happen. That anything got deleted at all suggests that the DELETE request is being made successfully.

Comment: Note: its not admins_photogalleries_path because there is no controller with photogalleries, instead its admins_photogallery_index_path :)

Answer (score 6):

I ran across the same problem and when I changed link_to to button_to everything started working correctly. Maybe because link_to is mainly used for GET calls and button_to for POST calls (in my case DELETE also).

Comment: Do add this as comment instead of answer

Comment: It is way out, but its js config issue.